# Extract substring from the last position in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, substring

I have got this one:

```
string = 'abcdefgh'
string(1:3) = 'abc'
```

Is this possible `string(-6:1) = 'abcdef'` .

I know this is not possible , what is the closest that is possible ; something which is similar to Python substring syntax.

Edit : I want to get rid of `.jpg`and `C:\` from `C:/hello.jpg`to get just `hello` . Using strsplit twice is just cumbersome . I just know the length of `C:\` and `.jpg`, but not of the whole string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `end` statement. This will point to the last character in the vector/matrix/string/whatever. So, for instance

```
string(2:end-1) -> 'bcdefg';
string(end-3:end) -> 'efgh';
```

Comment: Just a nitpick, [`end`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/end.html) is not a variable, but a built-in function/statement.

Comment: I know, I couldn't think of the right term for it. 'Function' didn't sound quite right, since that might suggest you pass the matrix to it as an argument.

Comment: I think I have to be content with this reply.